# Why was this question closed as not a real question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Why was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645554/modify-ckeditor-dialog-labels closed as "not a real question"?

The question seems valid to me.  It includes a labelled image showing that the individual was asking for so it's fairly clear.  Perhaps there's something about ckeditor that I don't know that warrants closing of the question as I see that it also has two down votes?

Comment: Is the question more than "Give me a library"?

Comment: I'm only slightly familiar with ckeditor, but I took the question as "how do I do this?" as in the label in the image.

Comment: I took the question as "can you google for the answer for me" which might have been changed with a more properly worded question or more details showing evdence of self research.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why I would consider this a candidate for "Not a Real Question":

- The question is incomplete; it contains no code that can be inspected, or inferred from context.
- There is no evidence that the OP made an attempt to solve their problem via research (looking through jQuery's API, Google, etc).
- The question is (likely) not helpful to others; it is very limited in scope to the OP's problem in this specific point in time.

Comment: Wow... I'm sorry I asked the question. But thank you for taking the time to answer. It seems there's some consensus in the community about the OP lack of effort. Not sure I agree with the last point though.  As someone who has used ckeditor, while I've found no need for this question (yet), I could see a possible use for it.